# Is it correct to say "write bigger"?

Tags: phrase-request

if a student in class can't see clearly what is written on the board, should he ask the teacher "Could you write bigger please?" If not, what would be the proper question?
Thanks.

Comment: That is exactly what this US English speaker would say!  I think I've heard it said in classrooms many times.

Answer (score -1):

This is standard slang accepted by most people, but as it is a little direct, (a little impolite), one could answer using a little more gentleness by introducing vocabulary to soften the tone, such as

> Could you please write a little bigger, I can't see of the words on the board.

or (add some humor)

> Would it be possible to write a little bigger, please, I'll get my vision checked when I book an appointment to the optometrist.

or a simple

> Would you mind writing a little bigger, I'm having trouble reading some words.

should suffice.

Comment: Although the example is idiomatic, the question is really whether it is correct to use a comparative adjective as a comparative adverb. While it's common to hear comments like **he won big** and **he did good**, these are hardly correct grammar!

Comment: Woah, there is a big difference between the examples "write bigger" and "he won big" and "he did good"... maybe you should go check up on whether or not big can be a comparative adverb..... 2nd basically tells you big can be used as an adv. I'm not even gonna get into if you bigger is an adv or not, because it is.....